# WooCommerce recent products pagination limit overall and per page

Tags: woocommerce, product, limit, pagination

I would like to show the latest 16 products on a page. But I only want to display 8 at at time.

`[recent_products limit="16" per_page="8" paginate="true" columns="1"]`

This should do the trick but it doesn't. I get 16 products per page and all products are accounted for the pagination.I have pages 1 to 124 in the pagination and would expect only to have pages 1 and 2.

How can I limit the the overall products AND products per page? Or is this simply not possible with the default shortcode? I don't want to install a plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Nope, I got rid of the pagination and am showing all 16 products on a single page.